# javascript window.print() prints in graphics mode consumes lot of time- how to make it print in text mode

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a web application:

In a particular use case, print-receipt. we pull up data from database and display it a new window ... followed by a `javascript::window.print()`

To print the content.

But this prints the browser window - in graphic mode.

The target printer, attached to the browser machine is a Dot matrix printer; and consumes a lot off time to print a single window (because of the graphic nature)

Can the printing be done in text mode ?

The printing makes very slow. please guide me.

Comment: I don't think there's an official option for that - it's kind of complicated and extremely rarely used. What browser are you using? The last time I had to deal with dot matrix printers, I wrote my own browser (based on Chromium)... Is that an option for you? I assume this is an application where you have control over the client machine's software, right?

Comment: @Luaan I have web application and it uses javascript print() method to print a page. It prints very slowly as compared printing from a notepad, So I decided to print from a notepad. So I first created a notepad and read it and print. But same issue. I am still facing very slow printing. Please guide me buddy. How can acheive speed like that same as we print from a notepad. My strong observation is that when we print from browser it prints in Graphics mode. I want to print in text mode please guide buddy.

Comment: Yes, that's very clear from your question. Focus on answering my questions :) It's very unlikely that a browser like Firefox or Chrome could be coërced to print in text-mode - it simply isn't useful in a graphical browser. And no, I can't share that browser, sorry. It's not too hard to make the necessary modifications if you have control of both the client and the server, though :) You could also make a browser plugin in such a case - for example, it's quite easy to do this with ActiveX and similar technologies.

Comment: Yes buddy I have control over server side. But client may use browser according to his own wish. We can't restrict that. But the thing is that they use only dot matrix printer. Any option to make to make graphics mode to text mode while printing. If not possible. Please guide me how to crack this issue :(.

Comment: I don't think there's any portable solution, sorry. Even converting from graphics mode to text mode is much harder than it sounds - you really want to do everything in text instead. There may be virtual printer drivers that try to convert from graphics to text, though there might be lots of issues. Browser extensions aren't portable, and you don't want to force a specific browser (custom or not). You could register a protocol provider application that will take an URL to print, but that's also far from trivial, and still needs an application installed on the client.